# Declaring and setting variable in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm currently using the following JavaScript in a Google Chrome Extension to automate the 'add to cart' process for purchasing sneakers on nike.com;

```
var size_i_want = "11";

function fRun()
{enter code here
// Select size option.
var sizesList=document.getElementsByName("skuAndSize")[0];
for(var i=0; i<sizesList.length; i++)
{
    if(sizesList.options[i].text.trim() == size_i_want)
    {
        sizesList.selectedIndex = i;
    }
}

var aButtons = document.getElementsByTagName("button");
for(var i = 0; i < aButtons.length; ++i)
{
    if(aButtons[i].className.indexOf("add-to-cart") > -1)
    {
        aButtons[i].click();
    }
}
}

function fTick()
{
if(document.getElementsByName("skuAndSize")[0] != undefined)
{
    setTimeout("fRun()", 600);
    //fRun();
}else{
    setTimeout("fTick()", 300);
}
}
setTimeout("fTick()", 300);
```

This script works perfectly for nike.com in the States, however does not work correctly for nike websites in other countries like the UK and Sweden.

As you can probably tell I am new to JavaScript and am still researching high and low to understand the language. However I understand this comes down to the fact that

```
var size_i_want = "11";
```

value is set as an integer (number) however on the Nike UK website the node that this affects contains letters, for example "UK 10.5".

Would somebody be able to help me declare a new variable and set it's value so that it contains both letters and numbers? I also have a feeling that this will impact the script as well, so help around that area is much appreciated too.

Comment: No, not possible with the given info. This script is based on the HTML document which gets values based on what is shown and/or entered on the screen. You did not provide the document in your write up. Also who knows how this string is used later in the code and if changing it the way you describe will break some service. Further more SO is not a site where you ask others to write code for you which is essentially what you are asking. My advice, find the programmer in your company who is responsible for this and work with them.

Comment: Thanks for the first half of your answer, but the rest wasn't necessary.  The amount of words you used to comment is probably more than the amount of code that I may have needed.

Comment: "I understand this comes down to the fact that `var size_i_want = "11"`" : What gave you that impression? I would argue that it's far more likely due to the fact that different sites have a different layout so perhaps it's `document.getElementsByName("skuAndSize")[0];` that doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

In javascript, variables are not typesafe, so you don't declare them as integers or strings. Coincidently:

```
var size_i_want = "11";
```

This is already a string. So you should already be able to add letters to it. Just change it to:

```
var size_i_want = "UK 10.5";
```

Comment: Hmmm thats what I originally thought and tried, however that doesn't seem to work. 

I think it's because the original script is from a .crx file and when I unpacked the .crx file to open and edit the .js file (i.e. change to var size_i_want = "UK 10.5"), something caused the error.

Answer (score 0):

As millerbr already said javascript is not type safe.

The mix of letters and numbers should not have impact on the script, because

```
size_i_want = "11";
size_i_want = "UK 10.5";
```

are both strings.

Comment: Hmmm thats what I originally thought and tried, however that doesn't seem to work. I think it's because the original script is from a .crx file and when I unpacked the .crx file to open and edit the .js file (i.e. change to var size_i_want = "UK 10.5"), something caused the error.

Comment: You have to uncompress the crx file.
Modify the value and the use chrome tools to compress it back to crx